# Why this happening when i set: RichHandler(console=Console())

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, python-logging, rich

**I was trying to set color to my custom logging label
everything worked fine but when i was using rich.progress then i saw this weird printing mistake (overflow).**

```py
import logging
from rich.logging import RichHandler
from time import sleep
from rich.theme import Theme
from rich.console import Console

FORMAT = "%(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(
    level="NOTSET", format=FORMAT, datefmt="[%X]", handlers=[RichHandler(
        console=Console(theme=Theme({"logging.level.success": "green"}))
    )]
)

log = logging.getLogger("rich")
log.info("Hello, World!")

#log.error("[bold red blink]Server is shutting down![/]", extra={"markup": True})

#log.error("123 will not be highlighted", extra={"highlighter": None})

logging.addLevelName(25, "SUCCESS")

import time
from rich.progress import Progress

with Progress() as progress:
    task = progress.add_task("Working", total=None)
    for i in range(0,100):
        if i < 30:
            logging.log(25, i+1)
        elif i > 30:
            log.warning(i+1)
        elif i >= 30 and i < 50:
            log.error(i+1)
        elif i >= 50 and i < 70:
            log.debug(i+1)
        elif i >= 70:
            log.critical(i+1)
        sleep(0.05)
```

see image here: https://github.com/Textualize/rich/assets/63346676/a37af0c7-02b4-4509-be9a-8b09c8b8db70)

i don't found any solution of this topic.

Answer (score 1):

In order for logging and Progress to work together, you will need to use the same `Console` instance. If you create a Console instance with your theme, and share it with the logger and Progress, it should work as intended.